# How to make datagrid columns editable

Tags: c#

I want to make 2 of columns in DataGrid editable. I tried changing readonly to false, but that didn't help.

So can anyone tell me any other way that I can try or is this something which is not letting it be editable.

Thanks

I went to DataDridView Task and on that particular column I changed ReadOnly 'false'. But this didnt help.
And yes it is a WinForm.

```
namespace Payroll
{
    partial class AttendanceLog
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            this.label11 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.btnShow = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.cmbMonth = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.cmbYear = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.dgAttendanceLog = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.btnSave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            this.slno = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.empId = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.empName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.workedDays = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.absentDays = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.weeklyOff = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.lateCominBy = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.earlyGoingBy = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgAttendanceLog)).BeginInit();
            this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label11
            // 
            this.label11.AutoSize = true;
            this.label11.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label11.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.label11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 42);
            this.label11.Name = "label11";
            this.label11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 13);
            this.label11.TabIndex = 106;
            this.label11.Text = "Month :";
            // 
            // groupBox1
            // 
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnShow);
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cmbMonth);
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label11);
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cmbYear);
            this.groupBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.groupBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.MidnightBlue;
            this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
            this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(688, 79);
            this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 108;
            this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox1.Text = "Select";
            // 
            // btnShow
            // 
            this.btnShow.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnShow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.btnShow.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(533, 34);
            this.btnShow.Name = "btnShow";
            this.btnShow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 33);
            this.btnShow.TabIndex = 108;
            this.btnShow.Text = "Show";
            this.btnShow.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnShow.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnShow_Click);
            // 
            // cmbMonth
            // 
            this.cmbMonth.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.cmbMonth.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cmbMonth.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Month",
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"});
            this.cmbMonth.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(83, 34);
            this.cmbMonth.Name = "cmbMonth";
            this.cmbMonth.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 21);
            this.cmbMonth.TabIndex = 104;
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
            this.label6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(283, 42);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 13);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 107;
            this.label6.Text = "Year :";
            // 
            // cmbYear
            // 
            this.cmbYear.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.cmbYear.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cmbYear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(341, 34);
            this.cmbYear.Name = "cmbYear";
            this.cmbYear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 21);
            this.cmbYear.TabIndex = 105;
            // 
            // btnClose
            // 
            this.btnClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnClose.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(625, 501);
            this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
            this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 33);
            this.btnClose.TabIndex = 9;
            this.btnClose.Text = "Close";
            this.btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
            // 
            // dgAttendanceLog
            // 
            this.dgAttendanceLog.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
            this.dgAttendanceLog.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
            this.dgAttendanceLog.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.dgAttendanceLog.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dgAttendanceLog.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.slno,
            this.empId,
            this.empName,
            this.workedDays,
            this.absentDays,
            this.weeklyOff,
            this.lateCominBy,
            this.earlyGoingBy});
            this.dgAttendanceLog.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 107);
            this.dgAttendanceLog.Name = "dgAttendanceLog";
            this.dgAttendanceLog.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.dgAttendanceLog.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(688, 388);
            this.dgAttendanceLog.TabIndex = 109;
            this.dgAttendanceLog.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgAttendanceLog_CellDoubleClick);
            // 
            // btnSave
            // 
            this.btnSave.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnSave.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.btnSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(544, 501);
            this.btnSave.Name = "btnSave";
            this.btnSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 33);
            this.btnSave.TabIndex = 110;
            this.btnSave.Text = "Save";
            this.btnSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSave_Click);
            // 
            // statusStrip1
            // 
            this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1});
            this.statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 545);
            this.statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
            this.statusStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(711, 22);
            this.statusStrip1.TabIndex = 111;
            this.statusStrip1.Text = "statusStrip1";
            // 
            // toolStripStatusLabel1
            // 
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel1";
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(298, 17);
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Note : Please Single click on respective field for manual entry";
            // 
            // slno
            // 
            this.slno.HeaderText = "Sl No.";
            this.slno.Name = "slno";
            this.slno.Width = 50;
            // 
            // empId
            // 
            this.empId.HeaderText = "Emp. ID";
            this.empId.Name = "empId";
            this.empId.Width = 75;
            // 
            // empName
            // 
            this.empName.HeaderText = "Emp. Name";
            this.empName.Name = "empName";
            this.empName.Width = 125;
            // 
            // workedDays
            // 
            this.workedDays.HeaderText = "Worked Days";
            this.workedDays.Name = "workedDays";
            this.workedDays.ReadOnly = true;
            this.workedDays.Width = 75;
            // 
            // absentDays
            // 
            this.absentDays.HeaderText = "Absent Days";
            this.absentDays.Name = "absentDays";
            this.absentDays.ReadOnly = true;
            this.absentDays.Width = 75;
            // 
            // weeklyOff
            // 
            this.weeklyOff.HeaderText = "Weekly Off";
            this.weeklyOff.Name = "weeklyOff";
            this.weeklyOff.Width = 75;
            // 
            // lateCominBy
            // 
            this.lateCominBy.HeaderText = "Late Going By (in Days)";
            this.lateCominBy.Name = "lateCominBy";
            // 
            // earlyGoingBy
            // 
            this.earlyGoingBy.HeaderText = "Early Going By (in Days)";
            this.earlyGoingBy.Name = "earlyGoingBy";
            // 
            // AttendanceLog
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(711, 567);
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSave);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dgAttendanceLog);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Name = "AttendanceLog";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Attendance Log";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.AttendanceLog_Load);
            this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgAttendanceLog)).EndInit();
            this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label11;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnShow;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClose;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgAttendanceLog;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbMonth;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbYear;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSave;
        private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn slno;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn empId;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn empName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn workedDays;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn absentDays;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn weeklyOff;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn lateCominBy;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn earlyGoingBy;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should describe your problem more precise. Post some code for example or tell us what exactly you are doing.

Comment: What happens if you NOT double click into the cell but single click into it? Into which column you click?

Comment: Most propably I found your problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found your problem. You most propably are using no DataSource or using a `ReadOnlyCollection` as Datasource. Then the DataGridView will not allow editing at all.

I have seen the same behaviour as you if I only add Rows to the datagrid. As soon as I use a `BindingList` as DataSource I am able to edit (clicking once into cell and start to type). You may think about removing your double click handler too as this interferes with the default behaviour.

This works for me:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string EmpId { get; set; }
}

public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // bind column to property of person
  empName.DataPropertyName = "Name";
  empId.DataPropertyName = "EmpId";

  // set our bindinglist of persons as datasource
  var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>();
  bindingList.Add(new Person(){ Name = "John", EmpId = "12345" });
  bindingList.Add(new Person(){ Name = "David", EmpId = "12346" });
  dgAttendanceLog.DataSource = bindingList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @BlueM it worked, in code it was readonly true, so just changed it and it works fine. Thanks a Lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

In the WinForms you can set EditMode property of the DataGrid to **EditOnEnter**.also readonly property of datagrid view should be false. then you can set ReadOnly for each Column.